# What format should a client (VLC player or browser) connected to an RTSP url receive?

Tags: python, opencv, streaming, rtsp

using Python I'm trying to upload OpenCV frames from a USB camera, and using an RTSP protocol, stream it live to be accessed by any client (web browser rtsp://ip:port, or VLC player). After days of searching, I'm still unable to find anything that could help, neither do I know how I can go about doing this.

1) What even is the format that rtsp streams should receive?? Is it an image or string or??? What format does VLC player even takes in? This is my primary question.

2) I read here

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169578&seqNum=3
and https://cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-many-ways-to-stream-video-using-rtp-and-rtsp/

That you can use TCP or UDP for an RTSP stream, but I'm using UDP here. Will this cause any issues when streaming the frames?

I have some code here which allows me to capture frames from the USB camera

```
import cv2
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5000

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #udp

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #========= What should I do here?
    FORMAT_OF_FRAME = What is the format that I should change the frame into?

    sock.sendto(FORMAT_OF_FRAME,(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

cap.release()
```

And after that, I should be able to look at the frames either by using VLC Player and running

rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000

or opening a web browser with that same URL

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply open a socket, RTSP is a fully working protocol, which you should implement if you want to use a raw socket. Do you really need a python program? Both ffmpeg (see the [streaming guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)) and gstreamer offer command line tools to stream from an input device via rtsp.

Comment: Yes, I really need it on a python program. This portion is actually part of a larger python program and I need them to run under a single script, which means I can't run command line tools to stream. Unless ffmpeg is able to stream single frames constantly, I don't think I can use it. I've read through the RTSP protocol but I really don't understand what I am supposed to do with it in order to use it with a raw socket, could you guide me please? Stucked on this problem until I can feel white hair growing out of my head

Comment: Well, if you wan't to use a raw socket, you must make a tcp server that implements the RTSP server side and when client sends a PLAY request send the frames to the client as an RTP stream. But that is a lot of work. Search for some already available packages that contain RTSP server functionality.

Comment: I'll try what you say and post back either once I'm stucked again or if I manage to resolve the issue, thank you!!